# How to pre-populate EFS with required files for starting containers in my pods in EKS

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, nfs, persistent-volumes, amazon-efs

I am moving my stateful flask application from single node server to EKS. I have decided to go with AWS EFS as my persistent volume option. The application needs few files (configs, trained ML models etc.) to start so my questions is -

1. Can I pre-populate EFS with required files before I apply K8 deployment yaml with PV, PVC?
2. If yes, then how do I place files exactly at the mountPath where my container can access it? This is a concern because I haven't applied the deployment yaml yet.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/efs-csi.html

Comment: You may add an init container to you deployment that may place the desired files for you. These files may be downloaded from an s3 bucket and then extracted to the desired location inside the EFS volume.